# Como restaurar variables de entorno W10

Tags: batch

He estado configurando por comandos en `cmd` las variables de estado para la instalación de JAVA_HOME en W10.

Lo que utilizo son los siguientes comandos:

Para crear la variable JAVA_HOME:

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"
```

Para agregar la ruta al PATH:

```
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

Sin embargo ahora deseo saber como puedo hacer para restaurar el sistema a como estaba antes de realizar los cambios con estas sentencias.

No es valido en mi caso hacerlo por la vía normal (windows+ variables+ enter + click variables, etc) porque ejecuto el procedimiento en muchos equipos y el coste de tiempo se vuelve importante.

Comment: Guarda el valor anterior con `set VALOR_ANTERIOR=%JAVA_HOME%`, después una vez hayas terminado de hacer lo que necesites, puedes volver a restaurarlo con `setx`: `setx -m JAVA_HOME "%VALOR_ANTERIOR%"`

Comment: depende para que lo quieras si solo sera para un uso temporal puedes usar `set` y lo quieres permanten es `setx` asi que dependiendo de lo que deses es la que usas!